# Force Close on line addOnCompleteListener use android 10 os. firebase notification

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification

This part of the code makes force close on Android 10. but it works fine on Android 8. How to solve it.

```
 if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
  //from notification
 String userId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userId");
 FirebaseUtil.allUserCollectionReference().document(userId).get()
 .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
 if(task.isSuccessful()){
 UserModel model = task.getResult().toObject(UserModel.class);
 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
 mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
 startActivity(mainIntent); 
 
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
 AndroidUtil.passUserModelAsIntent(intent,model);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
 }
 });
 }else{
```

can someone help me....
and I tried to delete that code without the code above. and runs fine on android 10.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  if(FirebaseUtil.isLoggedIn()){
  startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
  }else{
  startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginPhoneNumberActivity.class));
  }
  finish();
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.